# CPU usage shows high after switching from java 8 to java 10

Tags: java, cpu-usage, java-10

The same application behaves strange in java 10.
In Java 10 CPU usage shows much higher when compared to running in Java 8 or Java 7 even if the GC rate is low.

Comment: Thats correct, JDK9 have more multithreading overhead that usually not reproducable in development. All for debugging purposes.

Comment: could be any specific reason for it and any solutions available?

Comment: Reason is: For debugging purposes. There is nothing you could do.

Comment: Ok , but is it resolved in Java 11 then?

Comment: @PeterRader Do you have any source for that? Specifically, what do you mean by "not reproducable in development"?

Comment: @ohlec I wrote usually not reproducable

Comment: @PeterRader yes. Can you explain that, or even better link to some source on it? It seems very vague and mysterious.

Comment: Peter - what we are asking is that you provide either a *creditable source* to back up your assertion OR a benchmark that *demonstrates* the effect you say exists.  (One reason you apparently have difficulty reproducing the effect could be that it doesn't exist!)

Comment: @SreejithSS - The same applies to you.  If you want us to help you with this, you need to provide a tangible example that people can investigate.  And don't discount that the cause could be something else; e.g.  the overheads of Spectre mitigation

Comment: @StephenC  , Example is very simple scenario like below. I have an application that creates n numbers of threads based on the input . I have tested with 1000 threads with java 7 and java 10 . the CPU usage differs atleast 10 percent more in Java 10, but with low GC rate. Please note that all these threads are not stuck for a long time , they just doing their job and automatically ends

Comment: @SreejithSS can you reproduce that in the form of a [mcve]? Did you run both benchmarks under otherwise equal conditions?

Comment: I can try that . Bur the problem occurs under same conditions . Also I have noted when I set ParralelGC manually to Java options on Java 10 , The CPU is slight better

Comment: How does the troughput / latency of your application compare under the two different JVMs? It could be that Java 10 is *more* efficient than Java 8 (doing *more* work in the same amount of time).

Comment: @Sartorius Yes but CPU load will affect the entire application performance after sometime if Application runs for a long time that will affect the throughput

Comment: I will place my BaristiExecutor in Github and give a reproducable answer soon.

Comment: @PeterRader Any progress on that front?

Comment: @Sartorius Not yet, have to work between hollidays :) See, it has no impact because it a feature, the work is done faster, the application is faster. The CPU is used better, you should be happy.

Comment: @PeterRader I'm not the OP and I'm not convinced that his primary problem is a problem at all. You've been asked to back up your special claim that Java 9 adds "multithreading overhead" compared to Java 8 and you promised to provide evidence. I'm interested in your progress on that showcase, nothing else.